Best strategy and overall probability of success estimation for getting dated C++ - Ruby program to compile
This question has been edited in reaction to the helpful comments, thanks!
I am trying to get this PersonalRapidTransit simulation to run. It was written by John Lees-Miller 13 years ago. Unfortunately the Github repository is closed so I could not open an issue there.
The C++ code is exposed to Ruby using a wrapper that is automatically generated by SWIG.
For now my idea is to use old C++ and Ruby. For this I use the compiler flag c++11 or c++03, but I did not manage to install an older version of Ruby on my Ubuntu 24 system yet. I tried it with RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=$OPENSSL rbenv install 1.9.2-p330 and and the ruby version manager rmv, but ruby --version always returns ruby-3.2.3. Should I maybe rather try to it the other way round, i.e. adapting the C++-code to C++17 and using a new Swig to generate up to date Ruby code?
The complete output from running make in the terminal can be seen
here.
Resuming: What is the most probable to work/be true?

Use C++03 or 11 and Ruby 1.9.2 to use the code as it is.
Adapt the code, and regenerate with new swig to use up to date versions of C++ and Ruby.
Success chances of both option above are very low.


All C functions are supposed to be available in C++ as well (with the appropriate includes). Oh, and new size_t(size) is not a replacement for malloc, but allocates a single variable with the value size.

I'm not sure how high your pain tolerance is, but I would start by digging up an older Ruby version. (the repo mentions 1.9.2) If you're really motivated you can then start adapting the code to Ruby 3.x.

It's very unlikely that swig-generated code for Ruby 1.9 13 years ago will work in Ruby 3.2 today. You might be able to regenerate it.

The Ruby developers asked you for a bug report.  Have you considered writing one (against Ruby 3.2.0)?  Not that doing so will help you with your build, but it would be a community-minded thing to do.

This message ... "error: ‘calloc’ was not declared in this scope" ... means exactly what it says.  There is no declaration of calloc() in scope at a point where it is called. This is probably related to trying to use artifacts generated by an outdated SWIG with newer Ruby and C++.

You seem to have said that you tried compiling with -std=c99.  That's totally inappropriate for C++ code, so it's unsurprising that it did not resolve your issue.  For code of that vintage, your most likely choice is gnu++11, and c++11 is a reasonable second.  Other plausible alternatives include gnu++03 and c++03 ("plausible" in the sense that they are worth a try if neither of the others does the job).
